# Rails app didn't start - uninitialized constant Rails::Command::Actions::APP_PATH (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Gemfile

```
eval_gemfile('common_spree_dependencies.rb')
# Add your other gem dependencies below
gem 'rbs'
gem 'spree_core', path: 'core'
gem 'rails', '7.0.0'

gemspec
```

I am trying to run this app I am not a Ruby developer I don't know whats happening here.I read maybe the rails version is not supported.

```
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:10:in `set_application_directory!': uninitialized constant Rails::Command::Actions::APP_PATH (NameError)
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:131:in `perform'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/engine/commands.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
from script/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: you're running `script/rails` from spree_core, which is an *engine*, it only runs as part of the main app. which you should set up to get the rest of `spree`.

Comment: Thanks I will change that I need to run only the API

Comment: @Alex can you give me the right Gemfile to run only the api?

Comment: it's already api only frontend, you can remove spree_backend if you want and whatever else you don't need https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/getting-started/installation#installation